# Why does $Z \otimes Z$ have only two eigenvalues?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, quantum-information, density-operator, eigenvalue

The observable  $Z = \begin{bmatrix}1 & 0\\\ 0 & -1\end{bmatrix}$ on a single qubit system has two eigenvalues, 1 and -1, which means when measured, the system can give one of two possible outcomes.

Now if I have a two qubit system and the observable  $Z' = Z \otimes Z$, I would expect that physical measurement can give one of 4 possible outcomes (1,1), (1,-1) , (-1,1) and (-1,-1). However $Z' = Z \otimes Z$ has only two eigenvalues, 1 and -1, with two eigenvectors each.

I can understand why something like $Z' = Z \otimes I$ will have only two eigenvalues, but not able to see the physical intution behind why $Z \otimes Z$ not have 4 distinct eigenvalues with 4 distinct eigenvectors.

Comment: 1×1=1, 1×-1=-1, -1×1=-1,-1×-1=1

Comment: What do you mean with physical measurement? I can recommend J. Audretsch's book on entangled systems, where he explains how one can understand such an oberservable in terms of measurements.

Comment: @BySymmetry I think that OP is well aware of this, see the second paragraph.

Comment: I'm sceptical that the claim that there are only +1 or -1 eigenvalues as the correct answer. It should be two zeroes and then one +1 and one -1. It is definitely the case that there can be a physical situation to get the two +1 and two -1, but we should not be writing $\otimes$ for that situation. Please clarify what it is you are looking for.

Comment: I think I (wrongly) intuitively assumed doing a Z⊗ I followed by a I ⊗ Z , is the same as doing a Z ⊗ Z. I probably need to think about what Z ⊗ Z even means. 

An I ⊗ Z followed by a Z ⊗ I leaves the system in a |00> or |01> or |10> or |11> state. On the other hand a Z ⊗ Z leaves  it in one of the super-positions ( |01> + |10> ) or ( |11> + |00> )

@TobiasFünke's comment got me thinking in that direction. Will read the book for more.

Comment: I was about to post an answer before this questions was inexplicably closed. The gist is: just look at the action of the operator on the basis consisting of tensor products of the individual $Z$ eigenkets. The operator is diagonal in this basis and you can see the eigenvalues explicitly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A measurement, by definition, returns a real number, not a pair of real numbers.  If your "measurement" returns the value $(-1,1)$, you've made two measurements, not one.

Answer (score 3):

The matrix representing $Z\otimes Z$ in the basis $$|+\rangle \otimes |+\rangle\\
|+\rangle \otimes |-\rangle\\|-\rangle \otimes |+\rangle\\|-\rangle \otimes |-\rangle$$  is
$$
\left[\matrix{Z & 0_2\cr 0_2 &-Z}\right]= \left[\matrix{1 &0 & 0& 0\cr 0 &-1& 0&0 \cr 0&0& -1&0\cr 0 &0&0& 1}\right].
$$

Answer (score 1):

"Measuring an observable" means in practice, at least in the context where you talk about these Pauli matrices, to perform a projective measurement in the eigenbasis of the observable, assigning to each outcome a number equal to the corresponding eigenvalue of the observable, and then taking the statistical average of the numbers you obtain this way.

To measure $Z\otimes Z$, means to measure in the computational basis of two qubits, which indeed can result in one of four possible outcomes, which you might label as $(0,0), (0,1), (1,0), (1,1)$. Or equivalently with $(\pm,\pm)$ as you did. Note that each one of these is just a label, not a pair of outcomes. But if you are measuring pairs of qubits, you can also think of, say, $(0,1)$, as the label describing the outcome corresponding to finding the first qubit in $|0\rangle$ and the second qubit in $|1\rangle$.

But measuring an observable is not *only* measuring in its eigenbasis: it also entails assigning numbers to each one of the outcomes. Specifically, it entails assigning to each outcome the corresponding eigenvalue. So for $Z\otimes Z$, you're assigning to the outcomes $(0,0)$ and $(1,1)$ the outcome $+1$, and to $(0,1)$ and $(1,0)$ the outcome $-1$. In other words, you only get two outcomes because measuring $Z\otimes Z$ amounts to neglecting some of the information obtained from the measurement.